# Count exact amout of commas in lines of csv file (regex)

Tags: regex, linux, grep

i have a csv file (25GB) but it is corrupted. It has normally 47 columns seperated by 46 commas plus a starting comma so 47, but some rows have 49 columns. I want to delete those rows from the file and I thought I would use grep and a regex for that which I found in another question:

```
grep -vE '/^([^,]*,){47}[^,]*$/' file1 > file2
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Do not use regex delimiters. Remove `/`s.

Comment: agreed, `/regex/` is what you would use in `sed` , `awk`, `perl`, etc. Good luck.

Comment: What if commas are escaped of quoted?

Comment: there are no more commas in the file, only as delimiters for the columns- so thats fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest:

```
awk -F , 'NF==47' file1 >file2
```

This obviously doesn't work correctly for complex CSV files where some fields could contain commas inside double quotes which are not separators at all (... though maybe that's exactly the problem with your data).

Comment: this returns just one line of the csv in my case :/

Comment: commas are only seperators, no commas in quotes etc so thats good

Comment: Think you meant `NF`, not sure who upvoted, but clearly didn't read it...

Answer (score 2):

```
$ printf 'a,b,c\n1,2\n'
a,b,c
1,2

$ # -x option forces entire line to be matched
$ printf 'a,b,c\n1,2\n' | grep -xE '([^,]*,){2}[^,]*'
a,b,c
$ printf 'a,b,c\n1,2\n' | grep -xE '([^,]*,){1}[^,]*'
1,2

$ # you can also use awk, NF contains number of fields
$ printf 'a,b,c\n1,2\n' | awk -F, 'NF==3'
a,b,c
$ printf 'a,b,c\n1,2\n' | awk -F, 'NF==2'
1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

You describe a "starting comma", so your regex needs to take that into account.

`grep -vE "^,([^,]*,){46}[^,]*$" file1 > file2`

Or better yet...

`grep -vE "^(,[^,]*){47}$" file1 > file2`